# Converting of Uri to String

Tags: android, string, uri

Is it possible to convert an `Uri` to `String` and vice versa?
Because I want to get the the `Uri` converted into `String` to pass into another activity via `intent.putextra()` and if it's not possible can anyone suggest me a way how to pass selected `Uri` into another activity?

Comment: lol why is this question marked -2 ? `Uri.parse()` is not intuitive, and especially not when the reverse is `uri.toString();` (i would have thought it would be `Uri.stringify()` or something. definitely upvoting this question.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Uri to String

```
Uri uri;
String stringUri;
stringUri = uri.toString();
```

String to Uri

```
Uri uri;
String stringUri;
uri = Uri.parse(stringUri);
```

Answer (score 11):

Uri is serializable, so you can save strings and convert it back when loading

when saving

```
String str = myUri.toString();
```

and when loading

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(str);
```

Comment: Please provide more details. Add some notes about your choices. I think they could be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

using Android KTX library u can parse easily

```
val uri = myUriString.toUri()
```

Answer (score 3):

STRING TO URI.

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("YourString");
```

URI TO STRING

```
Uri uri;
String andro=uri.toString();
```

happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass a Uri to another activity, try the method intent.setData(Uri uri)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setData(android.net.Uri)

In another activity, via intent.getData() to obtain the Uri.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toString` method to convert Uri to String in java

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("Http://www.google.com");

String url = uri.toString();
```

This method convert Uri to String easily

Answer (score 0):

String to Uri

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com");
```

Uri to String

```
Uri uri;
String stringUri = uri.toString();
```