# How to convert the string to Uri after storing in shared preferences?

Tags: android, image, uri

I have converted Uri into a string by using toString() method and stored in a shared preferences.

```
String path = uri.toString();
```

I would like to convert back to Uri so that I can set the image. I have tried

```
Uri.parse(path);
```

or

```
Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
```

However, none of them works. How can I set the string back to the Uri?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356312/converting-of-uri-to-string

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487389/convert-string-to-uri

Comment: `Uri.parse(path); ` That should work. If not then tell the diffference for a second uri.toString(). Please tell values of uri.toString() so we can compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parse static method from Uri

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but I still haven't got what i really wanted.

Comment: Well then do not check this answer as the right answer. And further this looks like a very bad answer to me. Not to the point at all.

Comment: according to my question, this is the right answer but I think I am not asking what i really want since the picture is not displaying but the Uri.parse thing is correct.