# App restarts while updating data in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i try to add/update data in firebase database through this code my app ui freezes and app restarts after 3-5 sec.

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String username = findViewById(R.id.editText).getText().toString();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(username);
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("name",user.getDisplayName());
    map.put("userID",user.getUid());
    map.put("photoUrl",user.getPhotoUrl());
    reference.setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Ready to go",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

There was nothing in logcat but when i set it to no-filter
this thing keeps repeating in logcat untill i manually close the app from recent apps.I am able to read from firebase database but unable to write in it. the firebase realtime database rules are set to test mode

```
2019-06-13 12:04:52.578 712-712/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
2019-06-13 12:04:52.579 712-712/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
2019-06-13 12:04:52.579 712-712/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
```

Comment: Please add your database structure to see the path of the user that you want to update.

Comment: /Users/<username>/

Comment: Please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: How about you write the correct code from the start?

Comment: i tried but still the same

Comment: Can you share the logcat output please?

Comment: since the app restarts logcat gets clear

Comment: try `addOnSuccessListener` instead without any Toast for start , just to get a good feedback

Comment: i tried removing onSuccessListener completely but still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.getPhotoUrl()` returns `Uri` according to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users) , and according to [Basic write operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write) `Uri` is not one of them ,
 so write your `user.getPhotoUrl()` as `String` and retrieve it as as `String` , how ? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17356461/11555903)